# angular ngForm is not working on submittion

Tags: angular

Hi guys I am trying to implement ngForm but its not working.

html code: this is my html page

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="userLogin(loginForm.value)">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" ngModal>
<br> 
<br>
<button type="submit">Login/buttong</button>
</form>
```

ts code: ts page code is here

```
userLogin(form: NgForm) { console.log(form); }
```

module.ts code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DatatableTestComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

while submitting the form it doesn't access its value, didn't understand the issue bcoz I have followed the steps from tutorial video

Comment: What is the concrete error message? I have noticed that you are passing the form value to your method which accepts the entire form.

Comment: its not accepting the form value or showing it in log. Something like that.

Comment: I saw that you imported both the FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule. I suggest reading Angular's documentation. You should stick to one of the 2 distinct approaches. https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Why do you pass the form as a value to userLogin method? In the html try this: (ngSubmit)="onSubmit() and than in the .ts file: userLogin() { console.log(this.loginForm.value); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly in your example you wrote `ngMod(a)l` instead of `ngMod(e)l`.

Also, as @CarlitosJan noticed, you don't need ReactiveFormsModule for your form implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you have added FormsModule in the `app.module.ts`